# Presto SQL JOIN on columns with NULL values

Tags: sql, presto

Suppose I had the following 2 tables:

```
Table1:                      Table2:
C1:        C2:               C1:       C3:
a          cc                a         aaa
b          ff                b         bbb
<null>     jj                
c          mm                 
<null>     pp
```

Now, I want to join these tables on C1 and bring back the entire set to look like:
Results:

```
C1        C2:       C3:
a         cc        aaa
b         ff        bbb
<null>    jj        <null>
c         mm        <null>
<null>    pp        <null>
```

So, I tried a SQL like:

```
SELECT 
  Table1.C1,
  Table1.C2,
  Table2.C3
FROM Table1 
LEFT JOIN Table2
ON Table1.C1 = Table2.C1
```

But it isn't matching the NULL values from Table1 in C1, so I end up with:
Result:

```
C1:        C2:       C3:
a          cc        aaa
b          ff        bbb
```

How can I get the result I am looking for??
Thanks!

Comment: Your query should produce the result that you expect - that's what `left join`s are here for. You might have oversimplified your use case to the point where the problem is not happening anymore.

Comment: Tell detail where presto connector is pointing..

Comment: Do the values need to remain as NULL? For your use case, can a COALESCE with "Not Identified" work and match on that?